# Mocking ViewContext to test validation error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here's the story.  In order to be able to drop well-formed Bootstrap controls into my MVC forms, I'm building an `HtmlHelper` extension method that generates the following structure with a single command:

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </div>
</div>
```

The method itself isn't that hard to write.  What is considerably more difficult is the unit testing.  To make my extension method testable, I need to create an instance of `HtmlHelper<T>` using the appropriate mocks.  To that end, I have tweaked the answer to an old StackOverflow question and come up with this:

```
public static HtmlHelper<TModel> CreateHtmlHelper<TModel>(bool clientValidationEnabled, bool unobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled, ViewDataDictionary dictionary = null)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
        dictionary = new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() };

    var mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
        new ControllerContext(
            new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
            new RouteData(),
            new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object),
        new Mock<IView>().Object,
        dictionary,
        new TempDataDictionary(),
        new Mock<TextWriter>().Object);

    mockViewContext.SetupGet(c => c.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled).Returns(unobtrusiveJavascriptEnabled);
    mockViewContext.SetupGet(c => c.FormContext).Returns(new FormContext { FormId = "myForm" });
    mockViewContext.SetupGet(c => c.ClientValidationEnabled).Returns(clientValidationEnabled);
    mockViewContext.SetupGet(c => c.ViewData).Returns(dictionary);
    var mockViewDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();
    mockViewDataContainer.Setup(v => v.ViewData).Returns(dictionary);

    return new HtmlHelper<TModel>(mockViewContext.Object, mockViewDataContainer.Object);
}
```

So far so good.  Now that I can create an `HtmlHelper` object, I can execute my test as follows:

```
// ARRANGE
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
var helper = MvcMocks.CreateHtmlHelper<TestModel>(true, true);
helper.ViewData.Model = new TestModel { Field = null };
helper.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("Field", "The field must be assigned.");

// ACT
var controlGroup = helper.ControlGroupFor(m => m.Field, CssClasses.IconUser).ToHtmlString();
```

Here is the problem.  Within `ControlGroupFor`, whose signature is

```
    public static HtmlString ControlGroupFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string iconClass)
```

and which I haven't completed yet (being a good little TDD developer), I'm invoking `var validationMessage = html.ValidationMessageFor(expression)`.  Despite my use of `AddModelError`, the `ValidationMessageFor` method seems to think that `html.ViewData.ModelState["Field"]` is either null or its `ModelErrors` collection is empty.  I am inferring this because the value of `validationMessage` is

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Field" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

and according to Resharper, the `ValidationMessageFor` method calls down into this method:

```
    private static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string expression, string validationMessage, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        string modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
        FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();

        if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName) && formContext == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ModelState modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
        ModelErrorCollection modelErrors = (modelState == null) ? null : modelState.Errors;
        ModelError modelError = (((modelErrors == null) || (modelErrors.Count == 0)) ? null : modelErrors.FirstOrDefault(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ErrorMessage)) ?? modelErrors[0]);

        if (modelError == null && formContext == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("span");
        builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        builder.AddCssClass((modelError != null) ? HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageCssClassName : HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageValidCssClassName);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
        {
            builder.SetInnerText(validationMessage);
        }
        else if (modelError != null)
        {
            builder.SetInnerText(GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, modelState));
        }

        if (formContext != null)
        {
            bool replaceValidationMessageContents = String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage);

            if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
            {
                builder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-for", modelName);
                builder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-replace", replaceValidationMessageContents.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
            }
            else
            {
                FieldValidationMetadata fieldMetadata = ApplyFieldValidationMetadata(htmlHelper, modelMetadata, modelName);
                // rules will already have been written to the metadata object
                fieldMetadata.ReplaceValidationMessageContents = replaceValidationMessageContents; // only replace contents if no explicit message was specified

                // client validation always requires an ID
                builder.GenerateId(modelName + "_validationMessage");
                fieldMetadata.ValidationMessageId = builder.Attributes["id"];
            }
        }

        return builder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
```

Now, according to everything I've done, the `validationMessage` should give me a `span` with a class of `field-validation-error` and an error message reading "The field must be assigned."  In my watch window, `html.ViewData.ModelState["Field"].Errors` has a count of 1.  I must be missing something.  Can anyone see what it is?

Comment: I've made some progress: although `mockViewContext` and `mockViewDataContainer` are mocked to share the same `ViewData` property, my watch window seems to think that `html.ViewData` is not the same object as `html.ViewContext.ViewData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified the test to use `ViewContext.ViewData` rather than `ViewData` directly:

```
// ARRANGE
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();
var helper = MvcMocks.CreateHtmlHelper<TestModel>(true, true);
helper.ViewContext.ViewData.Model = new TestModel { Field = null };
helper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("Field", "The field must be assigned.");

// ACT
var controlGroup = helper.ControlGroupFor(m => m.Field, CssClasses.IconUser).ToHtmlString();
```

This has fixed my issue, but it's still not clear to me why `helper.ViewContext.ViewData` and `helper.ViewData` should be pointing to different instances, given the way the mocks were set up.